# Can not create a new jhipster project

Tags: spring-boot, yeoman, jhipster, yarnpkg, jhipster-registry

I created a new file and when I create a new jhipster project I got this error. How can I fix it?

> error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/chebbi/node_modules/@angular-cli'".
>   info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/chebbi/yarn-error.log".
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
>   Error jhipster
>
> ERROR! yarn install failed.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like a permission problem. You can try

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/chebbi/node_modules/
```

Comment: it gives me this error now : error An unexpected error occurred: "EPERM: operation not permitted, utime '/home/chebbi/node_modules/abbrev/LICENSE'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/chebbi/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error jhipster 

ERROR! yarn install failed.

Comment: try "npm cache clean" (without the quotes)